# SLDService of GeoServer is throwing NoSuchMethodError for RangedClassifier.getPercentages()

Tags: geoserver, geotools, sld

We've just installed SLDServer for GeoServer v2.17 (GeoTool v23).
When we call the attribute.xml we get the attributes of the layer, but when we call the category.xml
we get this error:

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.geotools.filter.function.RangedClassifier.getPercentages()[D
```

Even with the demo data and the demo url.

Are we missing something? Do we need to install some additional tools?

**EDIT**:
Build info.

- GeoServer v2.17.0
- Build Date 19-Apr-2020 11:07
- GeoTools v23.0
- GeoWebCache v1.17.0

[image]

Comment: are you sure you matched the versions correctly down to the third part of the version? can you add the build info from the `about GeoServer` page

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton, I've added the build info. Are you suggesting upgrading to the latest version might solve our issue?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the 2.17.0 version of the SLD Service - http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.17.0/extensions/geoserver-2.17.0-sldservice-plugin.zip ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a version mismatch, according to the [ticket](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6526) the addition of percentages to the `Classifier` was made to 22.3, 23.1 & 24-RC, but your GeoServer is built using 23.0 so the version of the SLD Service you should be using for 2.17.0 is [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.17.0/extensions/geoserver-2.17.0-sldservice-plugin.zip). If you are sure that you have the correct version of the extension then this is a release bug and should be raised on the GeoServer user list.